# Grouping and updating only some specific values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below data.

table name: t_keyword_count

```
f_id       f_keyword      f_count      f_dominant
==================================================
101        C++              2               0
101        Java             4               0
101        PHP              6               0
101        Python           5               0
101        Ruby             9               0
102        ruby             4               0
102        java             6               0
102        php              9               0
102        C++              7               0
102        Jquery           2               0
```

Like that

---

My Requirment is: I need update f_dominant status as 1 where I want top 3 f_count values with respect to f_id . i.e I want this result set

```
 101  ruby     9  1
 101  php      6  1
 101  python   5  1
 101  JAVA     4  0
 101  c++      2  0
 102  php      9  1
 102  c++      7  1
 102  jAVA     6  1
 102  RUBY     4  0
 102  JQUERY   2  0
```

Comment: presumably the PK is (f_id,f_keyword)

Comment: @Edper Look that only the first 3 have f_dominant = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END f_dominant
  FROM t_keyword_count x
  JOIN t_keyword_count y 
    ON y.f_id = x.f_id 
   AND y.f_count >= x.f_count 
 GROUP 
    BY x.f_id,x.f_keyword
 ORDER 
    BY f_id,f_count DESC;
```

or something like that

Comment: "Grouping and updating" means he want an UPDATE request not a SELECT one, does't he ?

Comment: He thinks he does, but he's wrong. You wouldn't normally store data that can be so easily calculated 'on-the-fly'.

Answer (score 0):

This works but it will probably be slow with too many rows:

```
update t_keyword_count t
  set f_dominant =
    f_count >= ( select f_count from
                   ( select * from t_keyword_count ) a 
                   where f_id = t.f_id
                 order by f_count desc
                 limit 2,1
               )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47504/2

Or this if updating done just once:

```
update t_keyword_count t
  set f_dominant = 1
  where f_count >= ( select f_count from
                   ( select * from t_keyword_count ) a 
                   where f_id = t.f_id
                 order by f_count desc
                 limit 2,1
               )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de3ec/1

Comment: But it updating 500 id's at a time. i have 60,000 id's in my database. How can i update those at a time. i have 6 tables like this. please help me